# Why does being in a (sub)directory break dependency injection?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have the following directory structure:

- Root

  - App

    - app.module.ts
    - app.component.ts
    - app.component.html
    - test.component.ts
    - services

      - auth.service.ts
    - test

      - test.component.ts

With the following files:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

//Modules/Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { TestComponent } from './test.component';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, TestComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [AuthService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div style="display:table; height: 100%; width:100%">
    <div style="margin:10px; height:100%">
        <test></test>
    </div>
</div>
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Creating Auth Service");
    }
}
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
export class TestComponent {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    }
}
```

This code works fine. **However** if I use the subfolder `TestComponent` and this app module:

**test/test.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
export class TestComponent {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

//Modules/Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, TestComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [AuthService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I get the error:

> Error in http://localhost:9893/app/app.component.html:4:8 caused by:
>   No provider for AuthService!

The only difference is the path for the service import and the path to the test component. I can't see why this should make *any* difference but clearly it breaks the dependency injector. If it matters, I am using Visual Studio 2015 with TypeScript 2.0 and SystemJS (based on the quickstart).

Why is this, and what can I do to fix it besides having all files in the same folder (it seems like that approach would get out of hand rather quickly).

**Update**
Making an "app" subdirectory and putting all app files in it (so every file uses the same relative paths) does allow the nested test.component.ts to work; so at least I don't need everything in the same directory. Would still be nice to know what I'm doing wrong though.